# Querying a table using KDB

Tags: kdb

How can i query a table using kdb
I created a table using the code following

```
q)name:`Iain`Nathan`Ryan`Ross
q)number:98 42 126 98 
q)table:([] name; number)
```

This creates a table:

```
name          number
Iain          98 
Nathan        42
Ryan          126
Ross          98
```

How can a query this table to return results of number which is equal to "98"
Or name which is equal to Iain

This is what I had been using

Comment: Have you read this article on [selects](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#select) from the kx wiki?

Comment: @Aaron91204 you should remove that comment and edit it into the original question. It's confusing and it looks like it's an (incorrect) answer to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a Q-SQL statement

`select from table where number=98`

The documentation for these this form of querying can be found at https://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/

Comment: Is there a way to search for the names as well such as Iain?

Comment: Yeah you can that would look like

```select from table where (number=98)and name=`Iain```

Comment: It is more efficient to use multiple `where` subphrases e.g. ``select from table where number=98,name=`Iain`` - this is more efficient as the second subphrase only has to run on the already filtered dataset